How to remove the leading/trailing spaces within $...$ in JavaScript?
This doesn't work and will give $1$ (expected: $1234$):
"$ 1234 $".replace(/\$ *(.+?) *\$/, "$$1$")

On the other hand,
"$ 1234 $".replace(/\$ *(.+?) *\$/, "$ $1$")

returns $ 1234$ correctly.

OK so what exactly is the question?

@Pointy the question is in the title: how to do $ 1234 $ -> $1234$. I have found the answer.

Isn't it just console.log("$ 1234 $".replace(/\s/g, ""))

@Haluk It is a simplified case. I have normal texts (not encompassed by $) elsewhere with spaces.

I have a solution for your query, but I am not able to answer, have you disabled anything?

I have tried to answer in comments, but due to lack of markdown features I can't.

Try this with different string:
"$ 1234 $".replace(/\$\s*(.*?)\s*\$/gm, (match, group1) => '$' + group1 + '$');

@Sparrow the question is voted to be closed so no new answer can be added. And I am not in a coding environment but using some regex replace functionality in a software (JavaScript/TypeScript based) so I cannot use a replace variant.

I will answer my own question: the replace string should be "$$$1$$":
"$ 1234 $".replace(/\$ *(.+?) *\$/, "$$$1$$")  // gives $1234$


You did right, but just using function instead of string as replacer.
"$ 1234 $".replace(/\$\s*(.*?)\s*\$/gm, (match, group1) => '$' + group1 + '$');
